# const reference and virtual template inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance

I post here because I'm not sure to understand why I encounter this problem.. Plus I have no idea how to solve it..

My goal is to build a Linear Algebra system with matrices and be able to retrieve reference on rows or cols, or submatrices.

I have a purely virtual class which defines the functions and keep the access to the element virtual:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
class densebase
{
public:
  using SubMat = submat<T,M-1,N-1,densebase>;
  using ConstSubMat = const submat<T,M-1,N-1,const densebase>;

  virtual T& coeff(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) = 0;
  virtual T& coeff(std::size_t index) = 0;

  virtual const T& coeff(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) const = 0;
  virtual const T& coeff(std::size_t index) const = 0;

  SubMat sub(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) { return SubMat(*this, row, col); }
  ConstSubMat sub(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) const { return ConstSubMat(*this, row, col); }
};
```

Then, I have the matrix class, which handle the data and override coeff functions

```
template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
class mat : public densebase<T,M,N>
{
public:
  // constructors..
  T& coeff(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) { return data_[row*N + col]; }
  T& coeff(std::size_t index) { return data_[index]; }

  const T& coeff(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) const { return data_[row*N + col]; }
  const T& coeff(std::size_t index) const { return data_[index]; }

private:
  std::vector<T> data_;
};
```

Finally, the submatrix class, which takes a reference on a densebase as parameter and overrides coeff functions in a different way:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N, typename parent>
class submat : public densebase<T,M,N>
{
public:
  submat(parent& m, std::size_t row, std::size_t col)
  : ref_(m), row_(row), col_(col)
  {
  }

  T& coeff(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) { return ref_(row + (row >= row_), col + (col >= col_)); }
  T& coeff(std::size_t index) { return ref_(index + (index >= row_),
                                            index + (index >= col_)); }

  const T& coeff(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) const { return ref_(row + (row >= row_), col + (col >= col_)); }
  const T& coeff(std::size_t index) const { return ref_(index + (index >= row_),
                                                        index + (index >= col_)); }

private:
  parent& ref_;
  std::size_t row_, col_;
};
```

The problem here came when I try to retrieve a submatrix from a constant matrix, I got the compilation error **"invalid initialization of reference of type 'float&' from expression of type 'const float'"**. I though coeff would always returns a reference, as it is defined..

The full error message:

```
||=== Build: Debug in ImDev (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Imagine\Imagine\demos\ImDev\main.cc||In instantiation of 'T& submat<T, M, N, parent>::coeff(std::size_t, std::size_t) [with T = float; unsigned int M = 2u; unsigned int N = 2u; parent = const densebase<float, 3u, 3u>; std::size_t = unsigned int]':|

C:\Imagine\Imagine\demos\ImDev\main.cc|206|required from here|
C:\Imagine\Imagine\demos\ImDev\main.cc|90|error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'float&' from expression of type 'const float'|

C:\Imagine\Imagine\demos\ImDev\main.cc||In instantiation of 'T& submat<T, M, N, parent>::coeff(std::size_t) [with T = float; unsigned int M = 2u; unsigned int N = 2u; parent = const densebase<float, 3u, 3u>; std::size_t = unsigned int]':|
C:\Imagine\Imagine\demos\ImDev\main.cc|206|required from here|

C:\Imagine\Imagine\demos\ImDev\main.cc|92|error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'float&' from expression of type 'const float'|

C:\Imagine\Imagine\demos\ImDev\main.cc||In member function 'T& submat<T, M, N, parent>::coeff(std::size_t) [with T = float; unsigned int M = 2u; unsigned int N = 2u; parent = const densebase<float, 3u, 3u>; std::size_t = unsigned int]':|
C:\Imagine\Imagine\demos\ImDev\main.cc|92|warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|

C:\Imagine\Imagine\demos\ImDev\main.cc||In member function 'T& submat<T, M, N, parent>::coeff(std::size_t, std::size_t) [with T = float; unsigned int M = 2u; unsigned int N = 2u; parent = const densebase<float, 3u, 3u>; std::size_t = unsigned int]':|

C:\Imagine\Imagine\demos\ImDev\main.cc|90|warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|

||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 6 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Did I missed something?

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: @Cyber I made it bold

Comment: I saw your summary of the message. I meant can you post the exact message that the compiler gave you, with the referenced lines of code, not just a snippet.

Comment: Well, this is pretty long, I edited the post

Comment: The message is helpful that it is telling you *what* is wrong, but it is also helpful to know *where* it is wrong. The compiler is probably pointing to the exact line that it does not like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using ConstSubMat = const submat<T, M - 1, N - 1, const densebase>;
```

should be

```
using ConstSubMat = const submat<const T, M - 1, N - 1, const densebase>;
```

to preserve constness.

Comment: Working like a charm, I feel so sad right now, I spent 2 hours on this problem ><